Symbology display issues in raster layers
The code below aims to apply symbology based on NDVI values ​​to the selected raster layer. However, after running the script it does not display correct information (image 1). I need to access layer properties and click OK or Apply to display correctly (image 2 and 3). In other words, the code works for its purpose but there is an error in displaying or loading the layer. I'm using QGIS 3.30, Linux Mint 21.3.
Band statistics for this layer:

STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0.93173605203629
STATISTICS_MEAN=0.67241566769275
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-0.69150775671005
STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.28242418703578
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100




ndvi_layer = iface.activeLayer()

stats = ndvi_layer.dataProvider().bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All, ndvi_layer.extent(), 0)

min_value = stats.minimumValue
max_value = stats.maximumValue

style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
color_ramp = style.colorRamp('RdYlGn')

shader = QgsColorRampShader()
shader.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)

min_color = color_ramp.color(0.0)
mid_color = color_ramp.color(0.5)
max_color = color_ramp.color(1.0)

items = [
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(min_value, min_color, f'{min_value}'),
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem((min_value + max_value) / 2, mid_color, f'{(min_value + max_value) / 2}'),
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(max_value, max_color, f'{max_value}')
]
shader.setColorRampItemList(items)

raster_shader = QgsRasterShader()
raster_shader.setRasterShaderFunction(shader)

renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(ndvi_layer.dataProvider(), 1, raster_shader)
ndvi_layer.setRenderer(renderer)
ndvi_layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()


You can use the createShader() method of QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer.
Example:
ndvi_layer = iface.activeLayer()
prov = ndvi_layer.dataProvider()
stats = prov.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All, ndvi_layer.extent(), 0)
min_value = stats.minimumValue
max_value = stats.maximumValue
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(prov, 1)
style = QgsStyle.defaultStyle()
color_ramp = style.colorRamp('RdYlGn')
renderer.setClassificationMin(min_value)
renderer.setClassificationMax(max_value)
renderer.createShader(color_ramp)
ndvi_layer.setRenderer(renderer)
ndvi_layer.triggerRepaint()

Result:

Side note: Since NDVI values are normalized with a fixed scale, I would consider setting the renderer classification min & max to -1 and 1 respectively (unless you just want to see local range/variation in NDVI values).
